# Optimize the query(mysql, php)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this..

```
select slno 
from `invoice_master` 
where slno NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Inv_slno from `invoice_refresh`)
```

I have more than 1,40,000 records in both tables(`invoice_master`, `invoice_refresh`)

this query taking hell out of time for execution. :(

this is the link for my explain query

[image]

Help me to figure out the alternate query..

Comment: So are there any indexes on the `invoice_refresh` table, particularly on the `Inv_slno ` column? If not, then consider creating one

Comment: We can't help you if you won't provide us with this fragment of database structure. Also informations about where do you have idexes set would be a great help.

Comment: primary key on slno from invoice_refresh and invoice_master is also having primary key on slno

Comment: Try `LEFT JOIN` instead: `select slno 
from invoice_master  AS m
LEFT JOIN invoice_refresh AS r ON m.slno = r.Inv_slno
WHERE r.Inv_slno IS NULL;`

Comment: Assuming that `slno` is a different column to `Inv_slno`; you need an index on `Inv_slno` otherwise your subquery will always be a full table scan

Comment: so, i will give index key for Inv_slno

Comment: Add that index, then retest the query with `explain` and see if the new index is picked up correctly for the subquery; but also test (and explain) using the JOIN alternative, which should be more efficient

Comment: wow..!! bingo @MarkBaker. I just added the index to Inv_slno the rows decreased to  721 from 1,44,000. and i just added a DISTINCT word before the slno. now, my results took just 0.456 secs Thanks Boss.

Comment: The Optimized query is :   select DISTINCT slno from `invoice_master` 
where slno NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Inv_slno from `invoice_refresh`)                          http://saiportfolio.freeiz.com/Answer.PNG Thanks again @MarkBaker Thanks alot.!! Now, Mysql is intresting :) :):D

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `NOT IS CLAUSE`

Have removed it,and used a `LEFT JOIN`

```
select 
slno 

from invoice_master 
LEFT JOIN invoice_refresh on (Inv_slno = slno )
where Inv_slno is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` :

```
SELECT m.slno 
FROM `invoice_master` m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `invoice_refresh` r ON m.slno = r.Inv_slno
WHERE r.Inv_slno IS NULL
```

Comment: I think an `INNER JOIN` whould be better : `select slno from invoice_master AS m INNER JOIN invoice_refresh AS r ON m.slno = r.Inv_slno` : This will exclude non matching rows

Comment: I started with an `INNER JOIN` ya, but that's the point, we need only non-matching rows.

Comment: these 2 queries left join and innerjoin will work perfect for matching rows. but i need non matching rows                                     http://saiportfolio.freeiz.com/explain2.PNG

Comment: http://saiportfolio.freeiz.com/explain4.PNG                                   I think, non-matching rows is difficult to fetch :(

Comment: Ok, made some test, and you can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead.

Comment: The Optimized query is : select DISTINCT slno from invoice_master where slno NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Inv_slno from invoice_refresh) saiportfolio.freeiz.com/Answer.PNG

Comment: I tried join and left join like this                                        SELECT distinct m.slno 
FROM `invoice_master` m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `invoice_refresh` r ON m.slno = r.Inv_slno WHERE r.Inv_slno IS NOT NULL; still it's processing 1,44,000 records.    Thanks @zessx for your time and immediate help. :)